# Jackson read only collections

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, kotlin

I have Spring Boot project with a post endpoint for a entity like this:

```
class Task{
    @JoinTable(name = "task_user",
        joinColumns = arrayOf(JoinColumn(name = "task_id")),
        inverseJoinColumns = arrayOf(JoinColumn(name = "user_id")))
@ManyToMany
var users: MutableSet<User> = HashSet()
}
```

I don't want people to be able to post users with the task, but @JsonProperty(access = READ_ONLY) doesn't seem to work on collections, so if I supply id's which exist, they are attached to the task anyway, does anyone have any idea if this can be done for collections in a similar way(I know it can be done using custom deserializers)?

Comment: You should avoid using the same object for both API and Persistence layer. Try to create a new object like `TaskRequest` only with the required fields and then, map it to the `Task` object in order to persist the entity.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot more sense, I don't know why I didn't consider that, have done it on previous non-Kotlin projects. I would still like to know how to not serialze collections though, seems like there should be an easy way to do it.

Comment: There is a reason that enterprise applications consist of different layers, and it's called "separation of responsibility". If you use an `Entity` in your controller, you will be fine with sending the `HttpServletRequest` to the DAO as well. You can spend a lot of time trying to solve this problem, and if you're an hourly employee that may turn out to be beneficial, or you can start with a cleaner design. Your choice.

Comment: I agree, and I completed a major refactor, accomplishing exactly that, however as I said, I would still like to know how to make a collection only serializable with Jackson, if I need it another time, since it's not obvious that it doesn't work with collections(unless I did something wrong and it actually does, or it's because of a Kotlin incompability)

Comment: Hey, did this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861877/1942642 answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

In order to ignore some fields on deserialization, you should use `JsonIgnoreProperties` with `allowGetters=true`. With this, the field `users` will be populated on serialization but ignored on deserialization.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "users", allowGetters=true)
class Task {
    @ManyToMany
    var users: MutableSet<User> = HashSet()
}
```

You can find more info on: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#allowGetters()